# css :checked target child element

Tags: html, css, target

I started to fiddle with the :checked pseudoclass to realize a small responsive menu. So far it works fine. What I want to achieve now is an "animation" of the menu-symbol.

In my CSS, I can target the actual #navigation with this

```
input.menu[type=checkbox]:checked ~#navigation{display:block;}
```

and toggle the menu that way. I can also target the label itself.

What I want to achieve now is targeting the three div-elements within the label. But I can't make that work. Is it possible and if yes, how? I tried all kind of variations like

```
input.menu[type=checkbox]:checked +label+.div1{<do stuff>}
```

etc, but it doesn't work.

Here's the snippet of the html:

```
<input class="menu" type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
 </label>
 <ul class="menu" id="navigation">
  ...
 </ul>
```

Oh, I want to stick with CSS only, JS is a last resort if it's not possible otherwise.

Comment: Use `input.menu[type=checkbox]:checked +label .div1 {<do stuff>}` As divs inside label are children so you must use space in between. `+` is for next sibling.

Comment: Perfect, so simple. Thanks a lot!